# Gtk: how do I pre-set / restore the selected printer?

Tags: printing, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

I'm writing a gtk program (in Python, but example code in C is OK).

I use a `GtkPrintUnixDialog` and want to save the printer settings between runs. Basically I'm calling `print_settings.foreach()` when saving and `.set()` when restoring). This works, **except** for choosing the actual printer – the call to `print_settings.set("printer",NAME)` is ignored and the dialog defaults to the user's default printer.

What's required to pre-select a printer in this dialog?

Minimal code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtkunixprint
import gtk

settings = gtk.PrintSettings()
settings.set_printer("QL-560")
ud = gtkunixprint.PrintUnixDialog()
ud.set_property('print-settings',settings)
ud.run()
```

Comment: This is unrelated, but GTK+ 2 is dead old. You should use GTK+ 3 instead, available since 2011.

Comment: Yes I know. But the problem manifests no matter what.